# Theravadian encyclopedia/ dictionary

Tags: theravada, reference-request, pali-canon, abhidhamma, books

Is there a reference text for the theravada tradition that contains a lists of concepts for quick reference? Such as a text that allows for reference of ideas found in the pali canon when reading, like the 5 aggregates, various lists from the abhidamma, four foundations of mindfulness, fundamentals to advance stuff,etc..
I know this stuff should be committed to memory and not just referenced when coming across in a text but that takes time so until then I am looking for a good physical resource since I don't want to use tech because I find it a hinderence to mindfulness and I am a recovery tech addict.

Comment: The index page of Ven. Bodhi's "In the Buddha's Words" book should have most of the fundamental concepts. For more advanced topics, use the index page of his "Comprehensive Manual of Abhidhamma" book.

Comment: Thank you I'm reading that now but in order only skipping to the footnotes, didn't think to check out the index.

Answer (score 1):

Former Bhante Varado made great Dhamma-Dana, but also other generous gifts of Venerables incl. giving broad, light as well deepened view on the Buddhas Dhamma:

> **[Pāḷi-Dictionary](https://sangham.net/en/dictionary/index)**
> Currently implemented dictionaries:
>
> - Buddhist Dictionary, by late Ven. Nyanatiloka Thera. (classical Theravada approach)
> - ATI Glossary, by Upāsaka John Bullitt.
> - Suttas and Dhammadesanā, addopted Cross-references from the ATI general-index. (basic words in simple language)
> - PTS Dictionary, by the Pali Text Sociaty (in progress).
> - Illustrated Glossary of Pāli Terms, by Venerable Varado Mahathera.

Three specials, not found elsewhere:

- all content is given toward Sangha and faithful followers (no copy-thieving)
- as open to give into (wiki-like), also way to work for liberation and not stay bond by consume (insight as side-effect of giving by keeping Silas)
- Content from various back-grounds and for various levels of insight as well as knowledge.

Search of words from every page best via search window (right upper corner), pre-listing sites ([dic]... marks dictionary pages).

Much insight by right pāmojja and muditā

Answer (score 1):

AccessToInsight has [A Path to Freedom: A Self-guided Tour of the Buddha's Teachings](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/index.html) and the [General Index by subject](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/index-subject.html). Both of these are helpful.

The book "[In the Buddha's Words](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003XF1LIO)" by [Bhikkhu Bodhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhikkhu_Bodhi) is an excellent anthology of the suttas. The PDF version can be found [here](http://promienie.net/images/dharma/books/sutras_in-the-buddha-words.pdf).

I strongly recommend this anthology as an authoritative outline of the most important concepts of the teachings, and I quote it below.

However, the sutta translations below may not all be from Bhikkhu Bodhi. They all come from [SuttaCentral](https://suttacentral.net), instead of the book. Also, some of the sutta numbers, especially those of Anguttara Nikaya, may not match the book, but they refer to the same suttas.

- The Human Condition

  - Old Age, Illness and Death - [SN 3.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn3.3/en/sujato), [SN 3.25](https://suttacentral.net/sn3.25/en/sujato), [AN 3.36](https://suttacentral.net/an3.36/en/bodhi)
  - The Tribulations of Unreflective Living - [SN 36.6](https://suttacentral.net/sn36.6/en/bodhi), [AN 8.6](https://suttacentral.net/an8.6/en/bodhi), [SN 22.7](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.7/en/bodhi)
  - A World in Turmoil - [AN 2.37](https://suttacentral.net/an2.32-41/en/sujato), [DN 21](https://suttacentral.net/dn21/en/sujato), [DN 15](https://suttacentral.net/dn15/en/bodhi), [AN 3.69](https://suttacentral.net/an3.69/en/sujato)
  - Without Discoverable Beginning - [SN 15.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.1/en/sujato), [SN 15.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.2/en/sujato), [SN 15.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.5/en/sujato), [SN 15.8](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.8/en/sujato), [SN 22.99](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.99/en/bodhi)
- The Bringer of Light

  - One Person - [AN 1.170-186](https://suttacentral.net/an1.170-187/en/sujato)
  - The Buddha's Conception and Birth - [MN 123](https://suttacentral.net/mn123/en/sujato)
  - The Quest for Enlightenment - [MN 26](https://suttacentral.net/mn26/en/bodhi), [MN 36](https://suttacentral.net/mn36/en/bodhi), [SN 12.65](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.65/en/bodhi)
  - The Decision to Teach - [MN 26](https://suttacentral.net/mn26/en/bodhi)
  - The First Discourse - [SN 56.11](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.11/en/bodhi)
- Approaching the Dhamma

  - Not a Secret Doctrine - [AN 3.131](https://suttacentral.net/an3.131/en/sujato)
  - No Dogmas or Blind Belief - [AN 3.65](https://suttacentral.net/an3.65/en/sujato)
  - The Visible Origin and Passing Away of Suffering - [SN 42.11](https://suttacentral.net/sn42.11/en/sujato)
  - Investigate the Teacher Himself - [MN 47](https://suttacentral.net/mn47/en/bodhi)
  - Steps Towards the Realization of Truth - [MN 95](https://suttacentral.net/mn95/en/bodhi)
- The Happiness Visible in this Present Life

  - Upholding the Dhamma in Society - [AN 3.14](https://suttacentral.net/an3.14/en/bodhi), [DN 31](https://suttacentral.net/dn31/en/sujato)
  - The Family

    - Parents and Children - [AN 4.63](https://suttacentral.net/an4.63/en/sujato), [AN 2.33](https://suttacentral.net/an2.32-41/en/sujato#33.1.1)
    - Husbands and Wives - [AN 4.53](https://suttacentral.net/an4.53/en/bodhi), [AN 4.55](https://suttacentral.net/an4.55/en/bodhi), [AN 7.63](https://suttacentral.net/an7.63/en/sujato)
  - Present Welfare, Future Welfare - [AN 8.54](https://suttacentral.net/an8.54/en/sujato)
  - Right Livelihood - [AN 5.177](https://suttacentral.net/an5.177/en/sujato), [AN 4.61](https://suttacentral.net/an4.61/en/bodhi), [AN 4.62](https://suttacentral.net/an4.62/en/bodhi)
  - The Woman of the Home - [AN 8.49](https://suttacentral.net/an8.49/en/bodhi)
  - The Community - [MN 104](https://suttacentral.net/mn104/en/bodhi), [MN 93](https://suttacentral.net/mn93/en/sujato), [DN 16](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato), [DN 26](https://suttacentral.net/dn26/en/sujato), [DN 5](https://suttacentral.net/dn5/en/sujato)
- The Way to a Fortunate Rebirth

  - The Law of Kamma - [AN 4.232](https://suttacentral.net/an4.232/en/sujato), [MN 41](https://suttacentral.net/mn41/en/bodhi), [MN 135](https://suttacentral.net/mn135/en/bodhi)
  - Merit: The Key to Good Fortune - [Iti 22](https://suttacentral.net/iti22/en/ireland), [AN 8.36](https://suttacentral.net/an8.36/en/bodhi), [AN 4.34](https://suttacentral.net/an4.34/en/sujato)
  - Giving - [Iti 26](https://suttacentral.net/iti26/en/ireland), [AN 8.33](https://suttacentral.net/an8.33/en/bodhi), [AN 4.57](https://suttacentral.net/an4.57/en/bodhi), [AN 5.148](https://suttacentral.net/an5.148/en/sujato), [Iti 107](https://suttacentral.net/iti107/en/ireland), [AN 8.35](https://suttacentral.net/an8.35/en/bodhi)
  - Moral Discipline - [AN 8.39](https://suttacentral.net/an8.39/en/bodhi), [AN 8.41](https://suttacentral.net/an8.41/en/bodhi)
  - Meditation - [Iti 27](https://suttacentral.net/iti27/en/ireland), [MN 99](https://suttacentral.net/mn99/en/sujato), [AN 9.20](https://suttacentral.net/an9.20/en/sujato)
- Deepening One's Perspective on the World

  - Four Wonderful Things - [AN 4.128](https://suttacentral.net/an4.128/en/sujato)
  - Gratification, Danger and Escape - [AN 3.103](https://suttacentral.net/an3.103/en/sujato), [AN 3.105](https://suttacentral.net/an3.105/en/sujato)
  - Properly Appraising Objects of Attachment - [MN 13](https://suttacentral.net/mn13/en/bodhi)
  - The Pitfalls in Sensual Pleasures - [MN 54](https://suttacentral.net/mn54/en/bodhi), [MN 75](https://suttacentral.net/mn75/en/bodhi)
  - Life is Short and Fleeting - [AN 7.74](https://suttacentral.net/an7.74/en/sujato)
  - Four Summaries of the Dhamma - [MN 82](https://suttacentral.net/mn82/en/bodhi)
  - The Danger in Views - [AN 1.306-314](https://suttacentral.net/an1.306-315/en/sujato), [Ud 6.4](https://suttacentral.net/ud6.4/en/anandajoti), [Iti 49](https://suttacentral.net/iti49/en/ireland)
  - From the Divine Realms to the Infernal - [AN 4.125](https://suttacentral.net/an4.125/en/sujato)
  - Perils of Samsara - [SN 15.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.3/en/sujato), [SN 15.13](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.13/en/sujato)
- The Path to Liberation

  - Why Does One Enter the Path? - [MN 63](https://suttacentral.net/mn63/en/bodhi), [MN 29](https://suttacentral.net/mn29/en/bodhi), [SN 45.41](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.41/en/bodhi), [SN 45.42-47](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.42-47/en/bodhi), [SN 45.48](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.48/en/bodhi)
  - Analysis of the Eightfold Path - [SN 45.8](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.8/en/bodhi)
  - Good Friendship - [SN 45.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.2/en/bodhi)
  - The Graduated Training - [MN 27](https://suttacentral.net/mn27/en/bodhi)
  - The Higher Stages of Training with Similes - [MN 39](https://suttacentral.net/mn39/en/sujato)
- Mastering the Mind

  - The Mind is the Key - [AN 1.21-30](https://suttacentral.net/an1.21-30/en/sujato)
  - Developing a Pair of Skills - [AN 2.31](https://suttacentral.net/an2.21-31/en/sujato#31.1.3), [AN 4.170](https://suttacentral.net/an4.170/en/sujato), [AN 4.94](https://suttacentral.net/an4.94/en/sujato)
  - The Hindrances to Mental Development - [SN 46.55](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.55/en/bodhi)
  - The Refinement of the Mind - [AN 3.101](https://suttacentral.net/an3.101/en/sujato)
  - The Removal of Distracting Thoughts - [MN 20](https://suttacentral.net/mn20/en/bodhi)
  - The Mind of Loving Kindness - [MN 21](https://suttacentral.net/mn21/en/sujato)
  - The Six Recollections - [AN 6.10](https://suttacentral.net/an6.10/en/sujato)
  - The Four Establishments of Mindfulness - [MN 10](https://suttacentral.net/mn10/en/sujato)
  - Mindfulness of Breathing - [SN 54.13](https://suttacentral.net/sn54.13/en/sujato)
  - The Achievement of Mastery - [SN 28.1-9](https://suttacentral.net/sn28)
- Shining the Light of Wisdom

  - Images of Wisdom - [AN 4.143](https://suttacentral.net/an4.143/en/sujato), [MN 146](https://suttacentral.net/mn146/en/bodhi)
  - The Conditions for Wisdom - [AN 8.2](https://suttacentral.net/an8.2/en/bodhi)
  - A Discourse on Right View - [MN 9](https://suttacentral.net/mn9/en/bodhi)
  - The Domain of Wisdom

    - By Way of the Five Aggregates - [SN 22.56](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.56/en/bodhi), [SN 22.82](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.82/en/bodhi), [SN 22.59](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.59/en/bodhi), [SN 22.45](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.45/en/bodhi), [SN 22.95](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.95/en/bodhi)
    - By Way of the Six Sense Bases - [SN 35.26](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.26/en/bodhi), [SN 35.28](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.28/en/bodhi), [SN 35.147](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.147/en/sujato), [SN 35.148](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.148/en/sujato), [SN 35.149](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.149/en/sujato), [SN 35.85](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.85/en/bodhi), [SN 35.234](https://suttacentral.net/sn35.234/en/bodhi)
    - By Way of the Elements - [SN 14.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn14.1/en/sujato), [SN 14.37](https://suttacentral.net/sn14.37/en/sujato), [SN 14.38](https://suttacentral.net/sn14.38/en/sujato), [SN 14.39](https://suttacentral.net/sn14.39/en/sujato), [MN 140](https://suttacentral.net/mn140/en/bodhi)
    - By Way of Dependent Origination - [SN 12.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.1/en/bodhi), [SN 12.20](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.20/en/bodhi), [SN 12.33](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.33/en/bodhi), [SN 12.15](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.15/en/bodhi), [SN 12.38](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.38/en/bodhi), [SN 12.44](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.44/en/bodhi)
    - By Way of the Four Noble Truths - [SN 56.24](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.24/en/bodhi), [SN 56.20](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.20/en/bodhi), [SN 56.31](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.31/en/bodhi), [SN 56.21](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.21/en/bodhi), [SN 56.42](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.42/en/bodhi), [SN 56.32](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.32/en/bodhi), [SN 56.25](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.25/en/bodhi)
  - The Goal of Wisdom - [SN 38.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn38.1/en/sujato), [SN 43.1-44](https://suttacentral.net/sn43), [Ud 8.1](https://suttacentral.net/ud8.1/en/anandajoti), [Ud 8.3](https://suttacentral.net/ud8.3/en/anandajoti), [Iti 44](https://suttacentral.net/iti44/en/ireland), [MN 72](https://suttacentral.net/mn72/en/sujato)
- The Planes of Realization

  - The Field of Merit for the World - [AN 8.59](https://suttacentral.net/an8.59/en/sujato), [SN 48.18](https://suttacentral.net/sn48.18/en/sujato), [MN 22](https://suttacentral.net/mn22/en/bodhi), [MN 73](https://suttacentral.net/mn73/en/sujato), [MN 70](https://suttacentral.net/mn70/en/bodhi)
  - Stream Entry - [SN 55.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.5/en/sujato), [SN 25.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn25.1/en/sujato), [SN 13.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn13.1/en/sujato), [SN 55.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.2/en/sujato), [SN 55.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.1/en/sujato)
  - Nonreturning - [MN 64](https://suttacentral.net/mn64/en/bodhi), [AN 4.169](https://suttacentral.net/an4.169/en/sujato), [SN 55.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.3/en/sujato), [SN 46.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.3/en/bodhi)
  - The Arahant - [SN 22.89](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.89/en/bodhi), [SN 48.53](https://suttacentral.net/sn48.53/en/sujato), [MN 22](https://suttacentral.net/mn22/en/bodhi), [AN 9.7](https://suttacentral.net/an9.7/en/sujato), [AN 9.26](https://suttacentral.net/an9.26/en/sujato), [AN 10.90](https://suttacentral.net/an10.90/en/sujato), [MN 140](https://suttacentral.net/mn140/en/bodhi), [SN 22.76](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.76/en/bodhi)
  - The Tathagata - [SN 22.58](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.58/en/bodhi), [Iti 84](https://suttacentral.net/iti84/en/ireland), [SN 47.12](https://suttacentral.net/sn47.12/en/bodhi), [MN 12](https://suttacentral.net/mn12/en/bodhi), [SN 56.38](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.38/en/bodhi), [MN 19](https://suttacentral.net/mn19/en/bodhi), [SN 22.78](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.78/en/bodhi), [AN 4.23](https://suttacentral.net/an4.23/en/bodhi)

Comment: Thank you for this intensely word reply, I shall spend many hours digging in to it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of lists here -- [Dhamma Lists](https://www.insightmeditationcenter.org/books-articles/dhamma-lists/).

There are also the Resources sections of https://www.buddha-vacana.org/

[image]

Comment: Thank you that list of lists is great.